# MongoDB very slow update on non-indexed field

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I am trying to debug to find a root cause on why single field update taking 60+ seconds, but not able to figure out. Will be great if you help me to get some direction on how to proceed.

- Scenario: updating a non-indexed date field on a collection.
- MongoDB Version :  3.0.12.  Storage engine: WiredTiger
- The query is using the proper index. scanned and modified are the same number of docs.

system.pofile document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa2e63b27001947449f1eed"),
    "op" : "update",
    "ns" : "abc.xyz",
    "query" : {
        "aId" : "5aa298dce4b0ef9feffe70e1",
    },
    "updateobj" : {
        "$set" : {
            "psdt" : ISODate("2018-03-09T17:36:31.277Z")
        }
    },
    "nscanned" : 20,
    "nscannedObjects" : 20,
    "nMatched" : 20,
    "nModified" : 20,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "writeConflicts" : 0,
    "numYield" : 5,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(26),
                "w" : NumberLong(26)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(26)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(6)
            }
        },
        "oplog" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(20)
            }
        }
    },
    "millis" : 69765
}
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `aId`? How many documents in the collection, and how big is your RAM? Note that MongoDB 3.0 is outdated. Could you try upgrading to the latest version (currently 3.6.3) and see if the issue persists? You would need to upgrade through successive major versions: 3.0 -> 3.2 -> 3.4 -> 3.6

Comment: @KevinAdistambha - Thanks for your reply.  Yes, I have an index on aId. and nScanned, nModified are same. Total size of the collection is 20GB.